# Pyglet: shape not drawn if I apply a TextureGroup

Tags: pyglet

I am trying to draw some shapes with texture maps applied via `TextureGroup`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import pyglet
from pyglet import gl

BASE_PATH = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

TEXTURE_PATH = BASE_PATH / "textures"


def load_texture(filename):
    return pyglet.image.load(TEXTURE_PATH / filename).get_texture()


class HexWindow(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        textures = {
            "desert": load_texture("hexmap-iso-desert.png"),
            "forest": load_texture("hexmap-iso-forest.png"),
            "hills": load_texture("hexmap-iso-hills.png"),
            "mountains": load_texture("hexmap-iso-mountains.png"),
            "ocean": load_texture("hexmap-iso-ocean.png"),
            "plains": load_texture("hexmap-iso-plains.png"),
            "swamp": load_texture("hexmap-iso-swamp.png"),
        }

        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        self.texture_groups = {
            name: pyglet.graphics.TextureGroup(texture)
            for name, texture in textures.items()
        }

        self._shapes = [
            pyglet.shapes.Circle(
                batch=self.batch,
                group=self.texture_groups["desert"],
                segments=6,
                x=0,
                y=0,
                radius=100,
                color=(50, 225, 30),
            ),
            pyglet.shapes.Circle(
                batch=self.batch,
                group=self.texture_groups["ocean"],
                segments=6,
                x=300,
                y=300,
                radius=100,
                color=(225, 30, 30),
            )
        ]

    def on_draw(self):
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0.3, 0.5, 0)
        self.clear()

        self.batch.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _ = HexWindow(1280, 720)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

If I remove the `group=self.texture_groups["ocean"],` args to my `Circle`s then I get a red and green hex.

But when I apply the texture group nothing gets drawn.

The textures work though, because I have some other code like this:

```py
class TexturedSquare:
    def __init__(self, width, height, xpos, ypos, texture):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.angle = 30  # degrees
        self.size = 2
        self.texture = texture
        x = width/2.0
        y = height/2.0
        self.vlist = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(
            4,
            ('v2f', [-x, -y, x, -y, -x, y, x, y]),
            ('t2f', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]),
        )

    def draw(self):
        gl.glPushMatrix()
        gl.glTranslatef(self.xpos, self.ypos, 0)
        gl.glRotatef(self.angle, 0, 0, 1)
        gl.glScalef(self.size, self.size, self.size)

        gl.glEnable(self.texture.target)
        gl.glActiveTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE0)
        gl.glBindTexture(self.texture.target, self.texture.id)
        self.vlist.draw(gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
        gl.glDisable(self.texture.target)

        gl.glPopMatrix()
```

If I add that to my `HexWindow` class then the textured square is drawn:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    # everything else as before, plus

    self.square1 = TexturedSquare(
        120, 120, 700, 300, textures["forest"]
    )

def on_draw(self):
    gl.glClearColor(0, 0.3, 0.5, 0)
    self.clear()

    self.square1.draw()

    self.batch.draw()
```

Why doesn't `pyglet.graphics.TextureGroup` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the Shapes module inherently does not deal with textures, so there is no texture coordinate vertex data being set. You will have to subclass the `Shape`'s and change the areas they set the vertex data to account for `t2f`, much like in your `TexturedSquare` example.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote some similar code in Kivy and had the same problem (using a custom `Mesh` sub-class for the shape) and the fix there was to specify the texture coords, so I suspected it was this. In Kivy the provided shape primitives like `Circle` and `Rectangle` provide the texture coords for their vertices, it's a shame the Pyglet ones don't.